# Any risk of injuries from barbell row wider than shoulder grip?

Tags: injury-prevention, barbell-rows

I bought a set of dumbbells that comes with an attachment to combine both dumbbells to be a barbell. If I only add plates on sides away from my shoulder, I can stack the weight to 24 kg max. If I add additional plates to sides closer to my body, the barbell can weigh 40kg max.
But the problem is I am forced to grip the barbell wider than my shoulder due to plates closer to my body occupied space that let me grip at shoulder length.

I had a few barbell row sets done with this setup and have no pain in my body so far. But I am worried that this may introduce problems in the long term as I was taught to row at shoulder length. Please let me know are there any risk of injuries with barbell row wider than shoulder grip.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Wide grip barbell row is totally fine, if done with correct technique of course.

Here are instructions on correct technique:

https://www.muscleandfitness.com/exercise/workouts/back-exercises/pronated-wide-grip-bentover-barbell-row/

Note: you may need to lighten the weight compared to narrow grip barbell rows as wide grip focuses more on upper back muscles.